# Create [tag:nintendo-network-id]+ synonymise [tag:nnid]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are some [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=nnid%20is%3Aq) specific about the NNID, but we do not have a tag for it yet. Those questions are mostly tagged as [3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds), [3ds-xl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds-xl) and/or [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking). I think we should create this tag, and retag the related questions.

If this is okay, I would also propose the synonym [nnid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nnid) -> [nintendo-network-id](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-network-id) (or vice versa, but I like the longer version more).

Comment: If okay, I can edit those 13 questions. Removing the unnecessary tags (such as 3ds) and adding [tag:nintendo-network-id]

Answer (score 2):

I just went through every single question including "Nintendo Network ID" or "NNID" and changed tag (and sometimes the body/title, if necessary).

I am not able to suggest to synonym [nnid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nnid) because I have not yet enough score in [nintendo-network-id](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-network-id), but I still think this should be added.

Comment: I'll do the synonym when I'm not on mobile unless another mod beats me to it.

Comment: Noticed this never got done, but I have completed it now.